# Deploying a static React JS app to Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a ReactJS app that I have deployed to GCP at Google App Engine, via the command:

```
$ gcloud app deploy --version 1
```

And it is working fine. However the app does not use a database. It takes the data from API requests from external sources via Axios library.

I would like to know if it is more efficient in terms of costs and performance, to deploy the app to a storage bucket, as a static build?  Would it be able to handle more requests with less cost? Or if does not make any difference?

Thank you in advance. Best

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to answer to so broad question, every solution can contain many details that will change costs.However Google gives tools to be able to analyze it depending of details of your solutions.

First thing is [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) which in helps you to estimate cost of particular technology used and if you know all technologies in your stack you can estimate total cost easily.

2nd thing is that you might don't know how much traffic, resources will be used by technology you will choose. This I can only imagine can be estimated by tests.  Then you can use [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/products/operations) to find how much resources your solutions will use.

I hope it will help!